# Prove the Riemann integrability of convex function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex. Recall that $f$ is convex if $$\lambda f(x) + \left(1-\lambda\right)f(y) \geq f\left(\lambda x + \left(1-\lambda\right)y\right), \forall x, y, \lambda \in [0,1]$$
Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

What is the easiest way to approach this problem?  We know that $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.  Can we assume that $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$?  Then it would follow that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $(a,b)$ for all $0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$ because it is a continuous, bounded function -- and so $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

If this is a valid approach, how would I prove that $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Every convex function is continuous.

Comment: @KurtG. continuous except possibly not at the end points.  I'm trying to figure out how to prove that $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ or if there is an easier way to go about this problem.

Comment: Right. I think it is not hard to show that $f$ is upper semi continuous on $[0,1]\,.$ Then it is [bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963718/upper-semicontinuous-function-attains-its-supremum) from above. I know you want bounded from below as well. Struggle!

Comment: This might help: $f$ is convex, hence $|f|$ is also convex and therefore bounded from above.

Comment: @KurtG. Are you really claiming $1-x^2=|x^2-1|$ is convex on $[-1,1]$? (The compositions 
of convex functions aren't necessarily convex)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ooops. Good point. $f(x)=x^2-1$ is convex on $[-1,1]$ but $|f|$ is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

- $L_1: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be the linear function defined by $L_1(0) = f(0)$ and $L_1(1/2) = f(1/2)$,
- $L_2: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be the linear function defined by $L_2(1/2) = f(1/2)$ and $L_2(1) = f(1)$,
- $L_3: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be the linear function defined by $L_3(0) = f(0)$ and $L_3(1) = f(1)$.

Then

- $L_2(x) \le f(x) \le L_3(x)$ for $0 \le x \le 1/2$, and
- $L_1(x) \le f(x) \le L_3(x)$ for $1/2 \le x \le 1$,

which proves that $f$ is bounded. As you correctly said, this implies that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$.

One can also show that the limits $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x)$ both exist, which means that there is a continous function $F$ on $[0, 1]$ whose restriction to $(0, 1)$ coincides with $f$. This also proves that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$.